# applying colors selection column in sharepoint list

Tags: xslt, sharepoint

I have a custom list with color and font size columns as below:

on the master page i have used a CQ webpart to show the list item as marquee by adding style:

```
<xsl:variable name="SafeLinkUrl">
  <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetSafeLink">
    <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="DisplayTitle">
    <xsl:call-template name="OuterTemplate.GetTitle">
      <xsl:with-param name="Title" select="@Title"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="UrlColumnName" select="'LinkUrl'"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:variable>
       <div>      
      <marquee direction="right" height="30" style="border:solid rgb(2, 174, 139); background: white;">
        <xsl:value-of select="$DisplayTitle" />
      </marquee >
    </div>
```

now i wanted to know how i can apply color and font selection in xsl format?